# Word to mean the specific component part of a honeycomb?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In the context of a math paper, I want to talk about the individual hexagonal parts of a honeycomb. "cells" can be ambiguous and "hexagonal prisms" is technically incorrect (the back of the cavity is angled outward).  "Repeating component part" is wordy and vague.  Is there a common phrase or word typically used for this?

Comment: Why would "cell" be ambiguous within the context of that paper? That's what the units are almost always called.

Comment: Because "cell" is also used for the component parts of a tissue, and I really want to avoid confusion or even momentary hesitation.

Comment: Are you also discussing tissue in this paper? If not, why not "honeycomb cell" at first use and "cell" thereafter?

Comment: I am not also discussing tissue in this paper, but I am referring to the cells in a very brief introduction that I probably won't repeat the phrase in.  Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @WindowsEscapist: "Tissue" has [more than one meaning](http://tissue.win.mofcom.gov.cn/www/19%5Ctissue%5Cimg%5C2007111914537.jpg), too, but that didn't confuse anyone when you used it in your remark.  Avoiding words with multiple meanings seems like an unnecessary self-imposed restriction, especially if you'll end up using more unusual words instead of standard terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to overlook 'technicality' a bit, *[hexagonal wax cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb)* would fit in perfectly.

Comment: This strikes the balance between specificity and conciseness.  Thank you.